# How to read emails from an Outlook 365 account without user interaction for credentials?

Tags: c#, office365, microsoft-graph-api

My use case is as follows. At regular intervals, a daemon process needs to:

1. Scan an email account in Office 365 for Non-Delivery Reports,
2. Extract some info from the email body,
3. Perform a task for the user account identified from that info.

My approach was to use Microsoft Graph (at which I'm new) to get in and do this - however if there is an easier approach please let me know. I'm having trouble with the .NET graph API in authenticating & getting tokens without user interaction.

I have been successful in using a Microsoft Graph console sample (https://github.com/microsoftgraph/console-csharp-connect-sample) to connect to the email account, after doing the usual setting up of the app and its permissions/scopes in Office 365, and using the App ID and "secret" to connect.

However, after spending a whole day researching and trying various ways to authenticate in the sample app, it always pops up a login window (see https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8vLU.png) before API actions can be performed. Sadly I've failed to discover how to authenticate and get tokens without user interaction.

Can anyone help me in how this sample needs to be modified - i.e. how the authentication needs to be altered - in order for it to work without asking the user to log in?

I do have full admin access, so can grant whatever permissions needed in Office 365, I just need help working out what to grant and what to alter in the console app to skip the user interaction. This is my first encounter with MS Graph and my head is spinning so please be gentle. :)

Note this will eventually run as a daemon on a server, but initially I'm just trying to learn by performing actions in this console app.

Answer (score 0):

This application sample is using a public client (that can't store secrets because you don't control the device/OS/environment) as you can see [here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/console-csharp-connect-sample/blob/98f9d86a6ab1011e91f470abc35d4eaec07b13b1/console-csharp-connect-sample/AuthenticationHelper.cs#L24).
[Here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/console-csharp-connect-sample/blob/98f9d86a6ab1011e91f470abc35d4eaec07b13b1/console-csharp-connect-sample/AuthenticationHelper.cs#L69) the acquire a token using apps public identity and user's identity (hence the prompt).
You have to replace it by a [ConfidentialClientApplication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identity.client.confidentialclientapplication?view=azure-dotnet) instead providing an additional secret (that you can generate from the portal) and then replace the acquisition by a [client only token request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identity.client.confidentialclientapplication.acquiretokenforclientasync?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Identity_Client_ConfidentialClientApplication_AcquireTokenForClientAsync_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_String__).
As your application is not going to hold any user identity none of the /me shortcuts are going to work.
Lastly, as you want to crawl all users, you need to change the permissions you're requesting to an admin permission/scope and replace User.Read and Mail.Read by User.Read.All and User.Read.All. (don't forget to click on the "grant permissions button" once you save the scopes.
Hopefully that helps